# ExpressJS instance management

Tags: node.js, express, web-applications

I want to create an app where user will be able to create web apps. This is not the hard part.
The thing I need help with is that I want to host all of these websites on a single domain, but with different routes.

Example, someone creates their webapp called "app1". The url of that app will be `mydomain.com/app1`.

The thing is that I want the main website to never be down. So when a user creates their web app, it will just add the url to the main web app.
I also want to add the possibility to manage every app as a separate express app.

Every app will be stored in a database and I will need some program to fetch every apps from the database and create the instance for it.

In the future, I even want to split the apps on different servers using subdomains (`sub1.mydomain.com/app1`)

If anyone has an idea on how I could do this, I would really appreciate it.

(I don't know if you understand because english isn't my first language)

I usually work with Pm2 to run my apps but I don't know if it will be useful in this situation.